# Changing opacity in hexadecimal doesn't work -heat map stop gradient-

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, opacity, rgba, hex

I have various hexadecimal RRGGBBAA colors as stop values in a heat map gradient but I have noticed that setting different Alpha values for some of the stop doesn't change the opacity in my code, I always get the same view -although setting the last two alpha bits to 00 as 0.0 opacity works for some reason-. The RRGGBBAA values are written like this:

`0xaa00007f`  (the last two bits, 7f should be 0.5 opacity)

`0xaa0000ff`  (ff is the 1.0 opacity)

The setGradientStops function that takes the stop values is like this -this is from a heat map library, not my code-

```
setGradientStops: function(stops) {


var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 256, 0);

for (var i in stops) {
  grd.addColorStop(i, 'rgba(' +
    ((stops[i] >> 24) & 0xFF) + ',' +
    ((stops[i] >> 16) & 0xFF) + ',' +
    ((stops[i] >>  8) & 0x7F) + ',' +
    ((stops[i] >>  0) & 0x7F) + ')');
}

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 1);
this.gradient = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 256, 1).data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that opacity expects a value in the range of 0 - 1 and there you are outputting a value in the range of 0 - 127. I would try...

```
grd.addColorStop(i, 'rgba(' +
((stops[i] >> 24) & 0xFF) + ',' +
((stops[i] >> 16) & 0xFF) + ',' +
((stops[i] >>  8) & 0xFF) + ',' +
(((stops[i] >>  0) & 0xFF) / 255) + ')');
```

So it takes the bits from the part that represents the alpha (all of them rather than almost all of them) by using the & bit operator on 0xFF rather than 0x7F. So...

```
0xFF (11111111) & 0xFF (11111111) = 0xFF (11111111) = 255
```

Rather than...

```
0xFF (11111111) & 0x7F (01111111) = 0x7F (01111111) = 127
```

and then you have the value in the range of 0 - 255, divide by 255 to get this to the required range.

```
0xFF / 255 = 1, 0x7F / 255 = 0.498, 0x00 / 255 = 0
```

So then for `0xaa00007f`, `grd.addColorStop` would be given the string `'rgba(170,0,0,0.498)'`